# Brightness options in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop missing

Tags: 12.04, brightness

I am unable to change the brightness of my desktop screen using this path.
System settings{top right corner of the screen)>Under Personal Brightness & lock.No option to change brightness is available here.In Ubuntu 11.04 <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> key was used to change brightness,the same doesn't work  in 12.04.

Also under System settings{top right corner of the screen)>Under Hardware Displays,my monitor is recognized as a Laptop despite me using a desktop!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

and change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Update your GRUB

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Restart your system** . Hope this works with you

I used to have the same problem and trying this half solved the problem , the directions work opposite but the brightness works...kind of workaround

Answer (score 0):

in  acer aspire 5741 I add edit in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and it is work well

Comment: Only the `acpi_backlight=vendor` part is important. The rest allies only to your system, which the OP may not have.